# DataFactory Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime as Parameter

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, continuous-integration, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to use a parameter to specify the name of the Azure-SSIS Integration runtime?

We are trying to set CI/CD with DataFactory into 3 Azure resource groups DEV/UAT and PROD. Each with there own DF and Azure-SSIS Integration runtime.

When selecting the Azure-SSIS-IR for and Execute SSIS package I can only select from the available list I cannot define a dynamic parameter.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I think you would do this with ARM templates. Use the variables to change the factory name and the IR. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-data-factory-v2-provision-ssis-runtime/azuredeploy.json and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-resource-manager-template#data-factory-json